# How to change the state with React TypeScript 2.0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

For such a small component created by React and TypeScript.

```
interface Props {
}

interface State {
  isOpen: boolean;
}

class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  private someHandler() {
    // I just want to turn on the flag. but compiler error occurs.
    this.state.isOpen = true;
    this.setState(this.state);
  }

}
```

When I tried to upgrade TypeScript 1.8 to 2.0, then I got the compiler error like below.

```
error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'isOpen' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
```

I guess maybe it caused by this change.

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-getters-without-setters-not-considered-read-only

so I just want to turn on the flag.

What should I do? Does anyone know the workaround?

Thanks.

## update

the quick workaround is just doing like the below.

```
this.setState({ isOpen: true });
```

Answer (score 4):

The way that you are doing it would be a problem even without typescript. 
This line specifically is a issue.

```
this.state.isOpen = true;
```

This line of code is attempting to mutate state directly which is not the react way of doing things and precisely what typescript is trying to enforce.

One way to work with changing state, is by making a copy of the state which in your case would look like this;

```
let state = Object.assign({}, this.state)
state.isOpen = true;
```

Now you have a copy of state and when changing your local variable you are not changing state.

Comment: This is a textbook example of the benefits of using some form of typing system like Typescript or React. It catches things like this, and helps you write correct, idiomatic React code.

Comment: This code snippet will not work in typescript 3.6 (and probably earlier). The read only is maintained through the Object.assign()

Answer (score 3):

Error occurs in

```
  private someHandler() {
    // I just want to turn on the flag. but compiler error occurs.
    this.state.isOpen = true;
    this.setState(this.state);
  }
```

Because `state` is not mutable. Lucky you are using TypeScript which is catching this for you at compile time.

## Correct code

You can merge the objects:

```
  private someHandler() {
    this.setState({...this.state, isOpen: true});
  }
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/spread-operator.html

Comment: Is this the correct syntax?

this.setState({...this.state, ...{isOpen: true}});

or

this.setState({...this.state, isOpen: true});

Comment: @MitsuruOgawa fixed 

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a class based component, setting the state with `setState()` method will merge the isOpen property to the existing state. So this will work:

```
this.setState({isOpen: true});
```